# I am not able to send SMS from Journey builder

Tags: sms, journey

I have created test DE added few fields including LOCALE and PHONE.

When I check Journey analytics it's passing but not getting SMS to my inbox.

[image]
[image]

Answer (score 0):

The contacts with Mobile Numbers that enter journey will never get sent an SMS text unless the Mobile number already exists in All Contacts in Mobile Connect via the method above or imported to All Contacts by file import.

PLease use the below article: https://help.salesforce.com/articleView?id=mc_moc_mobileconnect.htm&type=5